# Laravel controller not accessing json object

Tags: laravel

I have laravel controller as follows,

```php
public function webhookHandler(Request $request)
{     
    $amount= $request->amount;   
    echo $amount;
}
```

`$request` have json data as follows :

```
{
  "amount": "0.200",
  "amount_details": {
    "currency_code": "KWD",
    "amount": "0.200",
    "total": "0.200",
    "fee": "0.000"
  },
  "currency_code": "KWD",
  "customer_email": "mohamed_iskander@hotmail.com",
 
  "state": "paid"
}
```

I am unable to access json data in my controller...please reply

Comment: data is not getting in $request->all()..

Comment: `order_no` doesn't show up in your JSON?!

Comment: there is no data with the key ``order_no`` !!

Comment: sorry i have edited json file...instead of order_no need amount

Comment: Please, provide request headers and method. Seems like Content-Type header is applicatio/json, but it should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: ``$data = $request->getContent();``  and $data= json_decode($data, true); then dd($data) this should fix your error

Answer (score -1):

I have solve the issue by validaing json file as follows,

```
public function webhookhandler(){
 $json=$request->getContent();
 $cleared_json=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $json);
 $data = json_decode($cleaned_json, true);
 $amount= $data['amount'];
 echo $amount;
```

}

Comment: Seems your json data coming as string in '$request' object.